# Is the CUDA Occupancy Calculator provided by NVIDIA out of date?

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing

The [CUDA Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) lists the "Maximum number of threads per block" as 1024 for compute capability 2.x.

Is this information incorrect as I have read elsewhere that 512 is always the max number of threads per block? Also the [CUDA occupancy calculator](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/CUDA_Occupancy_calculator.xls) won't allow more than 512 for the "Threads Per Block" setting.

Edit: The Occupancy Calculator I was looking at was out of date. The newest version can be found on [this page](http://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-gpu-computing-documentation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a newer version available. Go to the CUDA 4.0 download page, and select "Documentation". Scroll down to find the CUDA Occupancy Calculator v. 2.4 (yours is 2.1, right?)

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/tools/CUDA_Occupancy_Calculator.xls

Here is a direct link to save you the effort.